# Any attempts at MongoDB on AIX

Tags: mongodb, aix

I have a project for which it would be desirable to run MongoDB on AIX 6.1 on a Power 6 box.  AIX is not a supported platform for MongoDB and I will have a bash at building it from source.  Has anyone tried this already?

I plan to use GNU G++ 4.2 PPC and I have the latest SCons running on Python 2.6, so the build tools run.

My initial impression is that there are a lot of platform dependencies in the .h files that I have encountered.  It does not look like a no-brainer by any stretch to get AIX/Power running.  Any words of wisdom whether it is or is not likely to be successful?

Comment: Im in a "me too" boat.   I've asked the mongodb community a few times and it seems pretty low on their list.   Sad for us AIX peoples.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to port several things as there is some very specific x86/x86_64 assembly as part of the MongoDB sources: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/platform/atomic_intrinsics_gcc.h Just like with ARM, this is not going to be a trivial task.

See some references:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1811
- https://github.com/wtfuzz/mongo-arm